# Can someone please explain to me why these two have different runtimes?

Tags: python-3.x, runtime

I was working on Leetcode with a friend. Our codes' logics are very similar yet his had a much better runtime complexity. However, I could only tell that both pieces of code should run in O(N) time. I don't understand why his ran better than mine.

My Code:

```
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        profit=0
        bought=prices[0]
        for x in prices:
            if x<bought:
                bought=x
            elif profit<x-bought:
                profit=x-bought
        return profit
```

My friend's code

```
class Solution:
    def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
        min=prices[0]
        max=prices[0]
        maxprof=0
        
        for x in prices:
            if min>x:
                min=x
                max=x
            elif max<x:
                max=x
                if maxprof<(max-min):
                    maxprof=max-min
        return maxprof
```

We were doing the "Best Time to Buy and Sell Stock" LeetCode question.

Comment: "yet his had a much better runtime complexity" how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Leetcode tells you the runtime + memory usage your code takes. Mine had a runtime of 1586ms while his had a runtime of 940ms.

Comment: Ok, and how did that help you determine the runtime complexity of yours and your friends code? You claim their runtime complexity is lower. Why?

Comment: Well, I would imagine that both codes have a O(N) runtime complexity due to that for loop. What I don't get is how his code ran faster than mine despite that we both should have O(N) time. Our coding structure is also pretty similar. Only thing I could reason is that he had a better runtime complexity, hence his faster time. But nothing about the code suggests that he has a better runtime complexity so...I'm complexed.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense. Having the same *runtime complexity* absolutely does not imply that the two pieces of code will have the same run time

Comment: Don't put too much weight into runtime values, especially since it is a single data point. They are dependent on a variety of factors. The time complexity is exactly the same and when I run this on leetcode they both run for 916ms. You should only look at this theoretically when calculating time complexity

Comment: Also, important to note, having a *better* runtime complexity doesnt' imply that the code will have a better runtime. This is crucial to understand.

Comment: Anyway, if you are going to ask a question like this, you *really* must provide some profiling code with your results. Not just tell us "leet code said this one is faster".

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for your inputs. Sorry that I couldn't provide any profiling code. I am kind of new to this.